# C program for finding the smallest integer amongst entered values

Tags: c

I want the user to enter any integer `n`. In the next line, `n` space separated integers will be entered. I want to find out the smallest integer among these `n` integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int x, y, z, a[x], p = -1, q;
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    y = 0, q = 0, z = 0;
    while (z <= x - 1)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &a[y]);
        if (a[y] <= p)
            p = a[y];
        y = y + 1;
        z = z + 1;
    }
        printf ("%d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a runtime error each time I try running this code on IDEONE.

Comment: When you wrote `a[x]`, did you think, even for a moment, what `x` *is* at that moment in the decl ?

Comment: Check for your declaration a[x]. What that means?

Comment: you can't have static array size at run time, like a[x]. x is not known when initialization is done for array a[x].

Comment: @pablo1977 I was trying to initialize a variable length array.

Comment: Enable all warnings and debugging information in your compiler. Learn more about pointers and heap allocation (e.g. [calloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3//calloc.3.html) etc...).

Comment: @surender8388 Not sure what you mean by that. C has variable-length arrays since 1999. (Yeah, OP is using them in the wrong way, but that's another thing.)

Comment: @WhozCraig I did not that I have to first enter `x` and then declare the array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @reb94 Well, what else would be meaningful, honestly? Statements are executed in order. That's just common sense.

Comment: My query has been answered. Please close this question.

Comment: @H2CO3... I just want to say, x is not known at the time he is doing memory initialization....Yep i mean same, the way he is doing that is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is here:

```
int x, y, z, a[x],
```

When you declare an array, the size of the array has to be known, either at compile time or (for variable-length arrays, introduced in C99) at runtime. `a[x]` is not a valid declaration, because you are declaring the array before the value of `x` is determined.

You can use the following for C99 or later:

```
int x, y, z, p = -1, q;
scanf ("%d", &x);
int a[x];
```

If you are using a pre-C99 compiler, then you need to figure out what the largest number of input integers you want your code to handle, and set the array to that. Then you can prompt the user for how many integers the user wants to enter, and store that in a different variable. After validating that value (to make sure it is not larger than the size of your array), you can use that variable to read the integers in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your one problem is initialization of `p = -1`. This would mean that the check `if (a[y] <= p)` would accept smaller values for `p` only if they are smaller than `1`. So, if you pass a set of values like `23 45 3 10`, then you would still get a minimum value of `-1`. One way to avoid this is to minimize it with the first input value.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a to have an uninitialized variable size `x`. Either assign some value to x ,declare a to have fixed value, or use dynamic memory allocation allocating the memory for a(e.g. with malloc) after you have read the value of `x`,

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @verbose answer, rather than setting `p = -1`, set `p` to the maximum int `p = INT_MAX`.  Then the first value entered will be less than or equal to it.